# get the ID of any Item in NavigateUrl in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello i have this gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grd1" width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False"   runat="server" EnableModelValidation="True"  CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"  >
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" />
        <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="Plan Reference" HeaderText="Plan Reference" SortExpression="Plan Reference" NavigateUrl="https://www.yahoo.com?itemid="/>
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center"/>
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
</asp:GridView>
```

When I indicate on the plan reference column , then the url appears in the bottom left corner of the window like this: `https://www.yahoo.com?itemid=`

I want the id of the row that I indicate on it , appear in the url in the bottom left corner of the window, how can I code it?

This is my CS code :

```
DataTable GetData()
{
    SPSite oSiteCollection = SPContext.Current.Site;
    SPWeb oWeb = oSiteCollection.OpenWeb();
    SPList oSpList = oWeb.Lists["Drill Plans"];
    SPListItemCollection oSpListItemCollection = oSpList.Items;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add("Plan Reference", typeof(String));
        DataRow dataRow;


        foreach (SPListItem oSplistItem in oSpListItemCollection)
        {
            //DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
            //string currentDate = String.Format("{0:dddd, MMMM dd, yyyy}", date);
            dataRow = dt.Rows.Add();
            dataRow["ID"] = oSplistItem["ID"].ToString();
            dataRow["Plan Reference"] = oSplistItem["Plan Reference"].ToString();
        }
        return dt;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Managers Approval" + ex.Message.ToString());
        return dt;
    }
}
```

Please help me.
I need a help for important work  please

Answer (score 0):

To append the `ID` of the bound item to the url you can use `Container.DataItem` like this:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField 
    DataTextField="Plan Reference" 
    HeaderText="Plan Reference" 
    SortExpression="Plan Reference" 
    NavigateUrl='https://www.yahoo.com?itemid=<%# Container.DataItem("ID") %>'/>
```

More info [here](http://forums.asp.net/post/2063352.aspx).

**EDIT**

In order for the above to work, you need to bind your `GridView` to the data table returned from method `GetData()`. In your `Page_Load` method you should have something like this:

```
if(!IsPostback)
{
    grd1.DataSource = GetData();
    grd1.DataBind();
}
```

Another approach would be to handle the [`RowDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event of your `GridView` and set the `NavigateUrl` in there. To do so, you'll need to assign an id to the `HyperLinkField` (let's call it "link"). Here is the code:

```
protected void OnGridViewRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    var hyperLink = e.Row.FindControl("link") as HyperLinkField;
    if(hyperLink != null)
    {
        var row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRow;
        hyperlink.NavigateUrl = String.Format("https://www.yahoo.com?itemid={0}", row["ID"]);
    }
}
```

Of course, don't forget to add the event handler in your markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grd1" RowDataBound="OnGridViewRowDataBound" ..
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Don't write anything in code-behind. The statement above is evaluated by the ASP.net engine and it should produce the url you want.

Comment: no...when i put this statement it appear like this:

Comment: i need to retrieve the ID of the row that i indicate on it

Comment: when i click on the row in plan reference column it not open the yahoo website and gives me this error:

Comment: Yahoo! - Help


Sorry, Bad Request.
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.


Please check the URL for proper spelling and capitalization. If you're having trouble locating a destination on Yahoo!, try visiting the Yahoo! home page or look through a list of Yahoo!'s online services. Also, you may find what you're looking for if you try searching below.

Comment: Well, it's kind of self explanatory - you're performing a bad request. I don't think Yahoo accepts such links.

Comment: the url is appear not in the url box of the website... its appear in the same page that i worked on it ,, on the bottom left corner of my site

Comment: i need behind (?itemid=) appear the ID of the row that i selected on the gridview

Comment: As I understand expression is not evaluated properly?

Comment: i want when i put the cursor on any row of the gridview appear the following on the bottom left corner of the site:

Comment: Cannot convert type 'System.Web.UI.Control' to 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLinkField' via a reference conversion, boxing conversion, unboxing conversion, wrapping conversion, or null type conversion

Comment: @Batoulkhawaldeh, put a breakpoint there and see what is happening. I cannot tell you what is the problem; I need at least a stack trace of the exception.